What is the average result of rolling Xd6 twice and taking the higher of the two sums?
In the Weird Wizard system, some "classes" get the ability to roll damage dice twice and take the higher of the two sums. The damage will be some number of d6s. So if I have, for example, 15d6 damage I will roll 15 d6's and add them together for sum1, then roll 15 d6's again and add them together for sum2. Finally I will pick the higher of sum1 and sum2, which will be the damage I deal. It's like rolling 15d6 with advantage.
To complicate matters, a common weapon perk in Weird Wizard is the brutal trait, that lets you reroll all 1's (and then takes the second result even if it is another 1).
I'd like to find a function for the average result of: roll Xd6 damage dice twice rerolling all ones once, then take the higher of the two sums.
I apologize if the question is already answered. I have searched both the forums and google, but English is not my first language, so I might not have used the best search terms.
Edit: Removed one of the questions, thank you for welcoming me and kindly reminding me of the rules!

Ugh, why would you design a system like this? I can sum dozens of dice in my head relatively quickly, but 15d6? Then rerolling all the 1s? Then rerolling the 15d6, and all the 1s it produces, for what's likely to be two pretty similar numbers? Advantage is good in D&D because you're dramatically reducing the swinginess. 15d6 has a really tight bell curve (the more dice you have, the less likely you are to roll high or low), so advantage just won't get you that much, and rolling and summing dice for the better part of a minute is tedious.

ShadowRager, 5e is similar wrt damage. In 5e, you get the 5d8 from smite and 5d8 from HexBlade added, lots of sneak dice added, you may or may not have brutal which rerolls 1&2s, etc. When it comes to hitting, Weird Wizard intends to keep the swing, and add d6s as boons or banes.

This is how I'd do it. This is slightly more compact that Vilarinof's solution, and also supports other die sizes than d6 and rerolls of results other than 1:
function: ROLL:n reroll BAD:s as REROLL:d {
  if ROLL = BAD { result: REROLL }
  else { result: ROLL }
}

DIE: [d6 reroll {1} as d6]

N: 5
output 1@2d(NdDIE) named "highest of two [N]d6 rolls, rerolling ones once"

Change the value of N to change the number of dice rolled.
Explanation:
1@2dX rolls two dice of type X (which could be just a number or a custom die) and selects the highest.
(More generally, P@KdX rolls K dice of type X and selects the Pth highest. And even more generally, e.g. {P,Q,R}@KdX sums the Pth, Qth and Rth highest rolls in KdX. But here we just want the highest of two rolls, i.e. P = 1 and K = 2.)
In this case, the custom die X that we want to roll twice and take highest is actually the sum of N dice (of type DIE). We could define it as X: NdDIE, but we can also just replace X directly with its definition (in parentheses, to stop AnyDice from parsing 2dNdDIE as (2dN)dDIE).
As an aside, we don't really need the variable N either, since we could just write output 1@2d(5dDIE) and get the same result. But having N as a variable lets me include it in the output string with "[N]". Having the variable N also allows us to do things like:
loop N over {1..5} {
  output 1@2d(NdDIE) named "highest of two [N]d6 rolls, rerolling ones once"
}

to generate the results for multiple dice pool sizes in one AnyDice program without having to copy-paste the output statement many times.
Finally, the variable DIE is a custom die that represents a single d6 with any rolls of 1 rerolled once. It is defined using a custom function that takes three parameters: ROLL representing the initial roll, BAD containing the list of values to be rerolled, and REROLL representing the new roll (which could be different from the initial roll).

The ROLL parameter is annotated in the function definition with :n to indicate that it should be a number. When we call the function and pass a die as ROLL, AnyDice will automatically call the function for every possible outcome of the die roll and collect the results into a new custom die.

The BAD parameter is annotated with :s, i.e. as a sequence. In the code above I do pass in a sequence, {1}, but actually the curly braces are unnecessary here since AnyDice would just convert plain numbers into single element sequences when calling the function. But I left them in as a hint for anyone modifying the code that you can pass multiple numbers, e.g. {1,2} to rerolls both ones and twos.

The REROLL parameter is annotated with :d, i.e. as a die, which is also what the value (d6) we pass in is. The reason for using :d instead of :n or :s here is to prevent AnyDice from calling the function separately for each possible outcome of the reroll, since we don't need that feature here.


(FWIW, there's one more kind of function parameter annotation in AnyDice, which is no annotation at all, and which just makes the parameter have whatever type you pass into the function with no automatic type conversion or calling the function multiple times. Technically we could leave BAD and REROLL without any annotation here and the function would still work, but I find it good practice to add type annotations to all function parameters unless you specifically need the function be able to receive multiple types of values for a parameter without automatic conversion. Knowing the type of each function parameter in advance just makes it easier to reason about what the function does.)

Ps. If I really wanted to golf this code down to its absolute minimum size, it would look something like this:
output 1@2d(5d{1,{2..6}:7})

This is the same code as above, except that I've removed the fancy output title, replaced N with its literal value 5 and replaced DIE with the equivalent expression d{1,{2..6}:7}. This can be interpreted as representing a 36-sided die with the number 1 on one side and each of the numbers from 2 to 6 on seven sides. Proving that a roll of this 36-sided die gives the same distribution of results as rolling a d6 and rerolling once if the first roll is 1 is left as an exercise for the reader. :)

Thank you so much for your answer! I am not able to accept both answers it seems. Your answer seems to be widely applicable, extensive and elegant, I approve!

Anydice can roll any dice - they don’t have to be real dice
Rerolling 1s on an \$N\$-sided dice, is equivalent to rolling an \$N^2\$-sided dice with one 1 and \$N+1\$ of every other number. So, for a 6-sided dice, it’s the same as a 36-sided dice with one 1, seven 2s, seven 3s, etc.
Also, comparing two dice pools and taking the highest is a built in function.
SIDES: 6 \ How many sides on the dice \
N: 15 \ How many dice \

DICE: {1, 2..SIDES:(SIDES+1)} \ Builds a dice that rerolls 1s \

output [highest of NdDICE and NdDICE]

Anydice
With slight tweaking, you can use a loop to do it all at once.

Rerolling 1s on an N-sided dice is also equal to rolling an (N-1)-sided dice and adding one. If we need to remove the rerolling complxity, isn't this easier than your way? (I'm not 100% sure, but I'm curious.)

@Zachiel Correct if you are rerolling 1s until there are no more. Here you get one rerolling and have to take that result

Thank you so so much! Very elegant to build the reroll 1s once die instead of making it a function.

I've written a dice roll calculator in Python.
d(n) returns an n-sided die
X+Y returns the distribution of the sum of X and Y
X&Y returns the distribution of the min
X|Y returns the distribution of the max
X*Y returns the distribution of the product of X and Y if X and Y are dice rolls. If X is an integer and Y is a dice roll, then X*Y returns the distribution of X copies of Y added together, and vice versa if X is a dice roll and Y is an integer. So for instance, d(6)*4 returns 4d6. d(2)*d(2) returns a distribution of 25% chance of 1, 50% chance of 2, and 25% chance of 4.
X**n returns a distribution of re-rolling ones n times (counting the first). That is, the maximum number of rolls, including the first, is n.
abs(X) returns the expected value of X.
So the result you asked for should be ((d(6)**2)*X)|((d(6)**2)*X).
I haven't done extensive testing, and for large number of rolls you'll run into float precision issues.
from itertools import groupby

class DiceRoll:
    
    def consolidate(probs):
        key = lambda prob : prob[0]
        sorted_probs = sorted(probs, key = key)
        return [
                (
                    value,
                    sum([prob for value, prob in value_probs])
                )
                for value, value_probs in groupby(sorted_probs, key = key)
            ]
    
    def __init__(self, probs):
        self.probs = DiceRoll.consolidate(probs)
        
    
    def broadcast(func, a, b):
        return [(func(v1,v2), p1*p2) for (v1,p1) in a for (v2,p2) in b]

    def gen_method(func, a, b):
        return DiceRoll(DiceRoll.broadcast(func, a.probs, b.probs))

    def __add__(self, other):
        return DiceRoll.gen_method(lambda a, b: a+b, self, other)
    
    def __and__(self, other):
        return DiceRoll.gen_method(min, self, other)
    
    def __or__(self, other):
        return DiceRoll.gen_method(max, self, other)
    
    def __abs__(self):
        return sum([v*p for v,p in self.probs])
    
    def __mul__(self, other):
        if isinstance(self, DiceRoll) and isinstance(other, DiceRoll):
            return DiceRoll.gen_method(lambda a, b: a*b, self, other)
        if isinstance(self, int) and isinstance(other, DiceRoll):
            return other * self
        if isinstance(self, DiceRoll) and isinstance(other, int):
            if other < 0:
                raise ValueError('Multiples of DiceRoll must be nonnegative')
            if other == 0:
                return DiceRoll([])
            if other == 1:
                return self
            if other == 2:
                return self+self
            if other%2:
                return (self*(other//2))*2+self
            return (self*(other//2))*2
        raise TypeError(f'Types were {type(self)} and {type(other)}. A DiceRoll and either another DiceRoll or an int were expected.')

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return self*other
    
    def reroll_ones(probs):
        ones_probs = [p for v, p in probs if v == 1]
        total_ones_prob = sum(ones_probs)
        not_ones = [(v,p) for v, p in probs if v!=1]
        re_rolled = [(v,p*total_ones_prob) for v, p in probs]
        return re_rolled.extend(not_ones)
    
    def __pow__(self, count):
        probs = self.probs
        if not isinstance(count, int):
            raise TypeError
        if count < 1:
            raise ValueError
        for i in range(count-1):
            probs = DiceRoll.reroll_ones(probs)
        return DiceRoll(probs)
        
        
def d(n):
    return DiceRoll([(k+1, 1/n) for k in range(n)])     

